# Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in

Tags: backbone.js

The following simple code throws an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in
>   Leo" in backbone-min.js:9

http://jsfiddle.net/nW7KF/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(n) {
        this.name = n;
    }
});

var user = new User("Leo");
</script>
</body>
</html>​
```

How can I make this code work with Backbone.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not constructing the model correctly. From backbone.js' [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-constructor):

> When creating an instance of a model, you can pass in the initial values of the attributes, which will be set on the model. If you define an initialize function, it will be invoked when the model is created.
>
> ```
> new Book({
>   title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
>   author: "Scheherazade"
> });
> ```

So you would construct your model like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nW7KF/2/

```
<script>
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var leo = new User({ name: "Leo" });
    console.log(leo.get("name"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to define the structure of the Model (User has a 'name') inside the model definition, rather than during instantiation?

Comment: Not to _define_ no, but you can override [Model.validate()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate), or use a plugin to enforce a schema on a model.

Comment: @tucson: There's also [`Model.defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) to help with that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error just the other day, and the problem turned out to be that I was using a newer version of Backbone (1.2.1), which evidently instantiates models a little differently than previously.  I have been using version 1.1.1 of that library, but when I updated to 1.2.1 I began seeing that same error.  When I reverted to 1.1.1 the error was no more. Might be something to look out for if you're seeing the same error and making the same library updates.

Comment: I had the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your files linked are outdated. Please update them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```